# How to avoid collision with the border or with each other by changing the heading i.e. rotate the object

Tags: java, javafx

- The task is actually, two cars moving, the cars must be able to avoid
  collision with the border or with each other by changing the heading 
  for example: *rotate the object.* **

  > I got an error for this 
  >   getRadius()

  ```
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
  import javafx.animation.Timeline;
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.image.Image;
  import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
  import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
  import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
  //import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;
  import javafx.util.Duration;

  public class Car extends Application {

      //public static Image car;
      public static Pane canvas;

      @Override
      public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

          canvas = new Pane();
          final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);
          scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

          primaryStage.setTitle("Car");
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);

          primaryStage.show();

          //export image
          Image car1 = new Image(new FileInputStream("src/car2.png"));
          Image car2 = new Image(new FileInputStream("src/car1.png"));

          ImageView c1 = new ImageView(car1);
          ImageView c2 = new ImageView(car2);

          c1.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
          c1.setFitWidth(100);
          c1.relocate(100,100);

          c2.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
          c2.setFitWidth(100);
          c2.relocate(600,100);

          c2.setImage(car2);
          c2.setVisible(true);

          //add to stage
          canvas.getChildren().add(c1);
          canvas.getChildren().add(c2);

          final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

              double deltaX = 3;
              double deltaY = 3;

              @Override
              public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                  c1.setLayoutX(c1.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                  c1.setLayoutY(c1.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                  c2.setLayoutX(c2.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                  c2.setLayoutY(c2.getLayoutY() + deltaY);


                  final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                  final boolean atRightBorder = c1.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - c1.getRadius());
                  final boolean atLeftBorder = c1.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + c1.getRadius());
                  final boolean atBottomBorder = c1.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - c1.getRadius());
                  final boolean atTopBorder = c1.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + c1.getRadius());



                  if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                      deltaX *= -1;
                  }
                  if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                      deltaY *= -1;
                  }
              }
          }));

          loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
          loop.play();


      }

      /**
       * @param args the command line arguments
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: `ImageView` does not have a `getRadius()` method

Comment: Always copy-paste the error-message (and stacktrace) if your post is about an error. So everyone sees the same as you and some may spot the issue immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, get the movement of the two cars fixed, so they stay withing canvas bounds.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Car extends Application {

    private Pane canvas;
    private static final String[] CIRCLES_128 = {
            "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Green.png",
            "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png",
    };

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        canvas = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Car");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Image car1Image = new Image(CIRCLES_128[0]);
        Image car2Image = new Image(CIRCLES_128[1]);

        ImageView car1 = new ImageView(car1Image);
        ImageView car2 = new ImageView(car2Image);

        car1.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
        car1.setFitWidth(100);
        car1.relocate(100,100);

        car2.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
        car2.setFitWidth(100);
        car2.relocate(600,100);

         //add to stage
         canvas.getChildren().addAll(car1, car2);

        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double car1DeltaX = 3, car2DeltaX = 3;  //each car must have its own deltaX and Y because
            double car1DeltaY = 3, car2DeltaY = 3;  //only one car has to change direction when hitting the edge

            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                car1.setLayoutX(car1.getLayoutX() + car1DeltaX);
                car1.setLayoutY(car1.getLayoutY() + car1DeltaY);

                car2.setLayoutX(car2.getLayoutX() + car2DeltaX);
                car2.setLayoutY(car2.getLayoutY() + car2DeltaY);

                final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                final Bounds car1Bounds = car1.getBoundsInParent();
                final Bounds car2Bounds = car2.getBoundsInParent();

                //check car1
                final boolean car1AtRightBorder = car1Bounds.getMaxX() >= bounds.getMaxX() ;//- bounds.getRadius();
                final boolean car1AtLeftBorder = car1Bounds.getMinX()<= bounds.getMinX() ;//+ car1.getRadius();
                final boolean car1AtBottomBorder = car1Bounds.getMaxY() >= bounds.getMaxY() ;//- car1.getRadius();
                final boolean car1AtTopBorder = car1Bounds.getMinY()  <= bounds.getMinY() ;//+ car1.getRadius();

                if (car1AtRightBorder || car1AtLeftBorder) {
                    car1DeltaX *= -1;
                }
                if (car1AtBottomBorder || car1AtTopBorder) {
                    car1DeltaY *= -1;
                }

                //check car2
                final boolean car2AtRightBorder = car2Bounds.getMaxX() >= bounds.getMaxX() ;
                final boolean car2AtLeftBorder = car2Bounds.getMinX()<= bounds.getMinX() ;
                final boolean car2AtBottomBorder = car2Bounds.getMaxY() >= bounds.getMaxY() ;
                final boolean car2AtTopBorder = car2Bounds.getMinY()  <= bounds.getMinY() ;

                if (car2AtRightBorder || car2AtLeftBorder) {
                    car2DeltaX *= -1;
                }
                if (car2AtBottomBorder || car2AtTopBorder) {
                    car2DeltaY *= -1;
                }
            }
        }));

        primaryStage.show();
        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then you can add a simple method to determine if two bounds intersect :

```
private boolean collisionDetected(Bounds b1, Bounds b2) {
    return b1.intersects(b2);
}
```

and use it in the loop:

```
   public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
            car1.setLayoutX(car1.getLayoutX() + car1DeltaX);
            car1.setLayoutY(car1.getLayoutY() + car1DeltaY);

            car2.setLayoutX(car2.getLayoutX() + car2DeltaX);
            car2.setLayoutY(car2.getLayoutY() + car2DeltaY);

            final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
            final Bounds car1Bounds = car1.getBoundsInParent();
            final Bounds car2Bounds = car2.getBoundsInParent();

            if(collisionDetected(car1Bounds, car2Bounds)){
                car1DeltaX *= -1;  car1DeltaY *= -1;
                car2DeltaX *= -1;  car2DeltaY *= -1;
            }

            //check car1
            final boolean car1AtRightBorder = car1Bounds.getMaxX() >= bounds.getMaxX() ;
            final boolean car1AtLeftBorder = car1Bounds.getMinX()<= bounds.getMinX() ;
            final boolean car1AtBottomBorder = car1Bounds.getMaxY() >= bounds.getMaxY() ;
            final boolean car1AtTopBorder = car1Bounds.getMinY()  <= bounds.getMinY() ;

            if (car1AtRightBorder || car1AtLeftBorder) {
                car1DeltaX *= -1;
            }
            if (car1AtBottomBorder || car1AtTopBorder) {
                car1DeltaY *= -1;
            }

            //check car2
            final boolean car2AtRightBorder = car2Bounds.getMaxX() >= bounds.getMaxX() ;
            final boolean car2AtLeftBorder = car2Bounds.getMinX()<= bounds.getMinX() ;
            final boolean car2AtBottomBorder = car2Bounds.getMaxY() >= bounds.getMaxY() ;
            final boolean car2AtTopBorder = car2Bounds.getMinY()  <= bounds.getMinY() ;

            if (car2AtRightBorder || car2AtLeftBorder) {
                car2DeltaX *= -1;
            }
            if (car2AtBottomBorder || car2AtTopBorder) {
                car2DeltaY *= -1;
            }
        }

    }));
```

---

[image]

---

The following is a refactored cleaner version:

```
public class Car extends Application {

    private Pane canvas;
    private static final String[] CIRCLES_128 = {
            "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Green.png",
            "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png",
    };

    private double car1DeltaX = 3, car2DeltaX = 3;  //each car must have its own deltaX and Y because
    private double car1DeltaY = 3, car2DeltaY = 3;  //only one car has to change direction when hitting the edge

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        canvas = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Car");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Image car1Image = new Image(CIRCLES_128[0]);
        Image car2Image = new Image(CIRCLES_128[1]);

        ImageView car1 = new ImageView(car1Image);
        ImageView car2 = new ImageView(car2Image);

        car1.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
        car1.setFitWidth(100);
        car1.relocate(100,100);

        car2.setFitHeight(100);//Resize image
        car2.setFitWidth(100);
        car2.relocate(600,100);

        //add to stage
        canvas.getChildren().addAll(car1, car2);

        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), t -> {

            //move 2 cars to new position
            positionNode(car1, car1DeltaX, car1DeltaY);
            positionNode(car2, car2DeltaX, car2DeltaY);

            final Bounds canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
            final Bounds car1Bounds = car1.getBoundsInParent();
            final Bounds car2Bounds = car2.getBoundsInParent();

            if(collisionDetected(car1Bounds, car2Bounds)){
                handleCollision();
            }

            //check car1 within canvas bounds
            if(atHorizontalEdge(canvasBounds,car1Bounds)){
                 car1DeltaX *= -1;
            }

            if(atVerticalEdge(canvasBounds,car1Bounds)){
                 car1DeltaY *= -1;
            }

            //check car2 within canvas bounds
            if(atHorizontalEdge(canvasBounds,car2Bounds)){
                 car2DeltaX *= -1;
            }

            if(atVerticalEdge(canvasBounds,car2Bounds)){
                 car2DeltaY *= -1;
            }

        }));

        primaryStage.show();
        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();
    }

    private void positionNode(Node node, double deltaX, double deltaY) {
        node.setLayoutX(node.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
        node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + deltaY);
    }

    private boolean collisionDetected(Bounds b1, Bounds b2) {
        return b1.intersects(b2);
    }

    private boolean atHorizontalEdge(Bounds enclosing, Bounds enclosed) {  
        return enclosed.getMaxX() >= enclosing.getMaxX() || enclosed.getMinX()<= enclosing.getMinX() ;
    }

    private boolean atVerticalEdge(Bounds enclosing, Bounds enclosed) {  
        return enclosed.getMaxY() >= enclosing.getMaxY() || enclosed.getMinY()<= enclosing.getMinY() ;
    }

    private void handleCollision() {
        //change cars directions
        car1DeltaX *= -1;  car1DeltaY *= -1;
        car2DeltaX *= -1;  car2DeltaY *= -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```