# JavaFX bounds issue?

Tags: javafx

So, using JAVAfx, which I painfully downloaded, I need to be able to move this ball, but not let it leave the bounds. Right now, I have it all set up, it just leaves the area. What am i doing wrong? Any tutors don't know anything about JavaFX, so I'm having trouble getting past this. Right now I tried to work it out, but keep getting this error Cannot Make a Static Reference to Bound

'''

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;

public class MoveBall extends Application {
        // create buttons
        Button left = new Button();
        Button right = new Button();
        Button up = new Button();
        Button down = new Button();
        Circle ball = new Circle(30, 30, 30);



        // action event class
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                // handle them
                @Override

                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        // movement of ball
                         if (event.getSource().equals(left) && ball.getLayoutX() >= (Bounds.getMaxX() + ball.getRadius())) {
                                ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() - 5);
                        }

                        if (event.getSource().equals(right)) {
                                ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() + 5);
                        }

                        if (event.getSource().equals(up)) {
                                ball.setCenterY(ball.getCenterY() - 5);
                        }

                        if (event.getSource().equals(down) && ball.getCenterY() < 400)) {
                                ball.setCenterY(ball.getCenterY() + 5);
                        }
                }
        };

        // main method
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Application.launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

                primaryStage.setTitle("Ball Movement");
                ball.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                ball.setFill(null);
                // button location
                left.setLayoutX(100);
                left.setLayoutY(210);
                left.setText("Left");
                // button event
                left.setOnAction(event);

                // similar for all button
                right.setLayoutX(150);
                right.setLayoutY(210);
                right.setText("Right");
                right.setOnAction(event);

                // button location
                up.setLayoutX(200);
                up.setLayoutY(210);
                up.setText("Up");
                // button event
                up.setOnAction(event);

                // similar for all button
                down.setLayoutX(250);
                down.setLayoutY(210);
                down.setText("Down");
                down.setOnAction(event);

                Group root = new Group();

                // add to a group
                root.getChildren().add(left);
                root.getChildren().add(right);
                root.getChildren().add(up);
                root.getChildren().add(down);
                root.getChildren().add(ball);

                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE));
                // show the scene
                primaryStage.show();
        }
}
```

'''

Comment: What do expect Bounds.getMaxX() to return? Bounds of what? More formally: The Bounds class does not have a static method getMaxX(). Therefore the complaint. If you want to check for some bounds you first have to define them and get a Bounds instance.

Comment: JavaFX has a Bound library which already does this I thought?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `root.getLayoutBounds` (and possibly `circle.getBoundsInParent`); if you don't want to rely on the scene structure there's also `node.localToScene` to transform the local bounds...

Comment: @JennaM Yes, but do you think any framework could just guess right which bounds you mean. Just follow fabian examples and decide on which bounds you want to work with.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041465/3992939) answer for checking bounds of moving balls.