# How do I reflect an angle of a Point2D object

Tags: java, javafx, pong

I'm trying to make a pong game using JavaFX and I've decided to use Point2D for the paddle and ball positions.

I created this method to check for wall collisions

```
    public void checkWallCollision(){
        boolean ballHitBottom = posBall.getY() > 500;
        boolean ballHitTop = posBall.getY() < 50;
        boolean ballHitLeft = posBall.getX() < 0;
        boolean ballHitRight = posBall.getX() > 725;

        if (ballHitTop || ballHitBottom){
            ballDirVector = ballDirVector.multiply(-1);
        }
        if(ballHitLeft || ballHitRight){
            ballDirVector = ballDirVector.multiply(-1);
        }
    }
```

But with a Point2D object like that, I can't just multiply it like that. I need the angle to be reflected. I guess another thing I could show to help is how I launch the ball. In this method I do have the angle, but I'm not sure what way I should go about accessing it.

```
    public void launchBall(){
        // Launch the ball
        boolean ballDirection = random.nextBoolean();
        // bound to an acute angle on start
        double ballAngle = Constants._PADDLE_ANGLES[random.nextInt(5) + 1];
        if (ballDirection){
            ballAngle *= -1;
        }
        ballSpeed = Constants._BallStartSpeed;
        ballDirVector = new Point2D(Math.cos(ballAngle), Math.sin(ballAngle));
    }
```

Comment: If your velocity vector is (vx, vy), then after reflecting off a vertical line it is just (-vx, vy), and off a horizontal line (vx, -vy), you don't need to worry about angles. You can just create a new Point2D.

Comment: See an example of collision detection and bouncing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041465/3992939)